# Split a string by another string except by

Tags: c#, regex, split, except

I want to split with Regex this line using the separator `:` except when the segment contains `?:`

```
string input = "AV Rocket 456:Contact?:Jane or Tarza:URL?:http?://www.jane.com:Delivered 18?:15:Product Description";
```

I tried with

```
string pattern = @"[^\?:]\:";
```

But the last char at all elements are cutted,

I am waiting for this result:

> 'AV Rocket 456'
>  'CONTACT?:JANE OR TARZAN'
>   'URL?:http?://www.jane.com'
>  'Time Delivered 18?:15'
>  'Product
>   Description'

https://dotnetfiddle.net/PeVuMM

Comment: You mean you need output like "AV Rocket 456:" ?

Comment: `string pattern = @"(?<!\?):";`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: Make this comment an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood your question, the below sample will give the intended output :)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Xunit;

namespace XUnitTestProject1
{
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [Fact]
        public void TestPatternSplit()
        {

            var input = @"AV Rocket 456:Contact?:Jane or Tarzan:URL?:http?://www.jane.com:Time Delivered 18?:15:Product Description";

            var output = PatternSplit(input);

            var expected = new[]{"AV Rocket 456", "Contact?:Jane or Tarzan", "URL?:http?://www.jane.com","Time Delivered 18?:15","Product Description"};

            Assert.Equal(expected, output);

        }

        private static IEnumerable<string> PatternSplit(string input)
        {
            const string  pattern = @"(?<!\?):";
            return Regex.Split(input, pattern);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated fiddler https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZF5TP1